# How to bind a Control.Property to a property in the code-behind?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, code-behind

I have a TextBox in my WPF window.

I have a property in the code behind called Text as well.

I want the text property to be bound to the Text property (i.e. when the value changes in the property the textbox value should also be updadated.

Thanks

Comment: The title of your question is confusing as there is no boolean property in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the DataContext of the TextBox control (or of any of its parents) to your window:

```
myTextBox.DataContext = this;
```

then in your XAML:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Text} x:Name="myTextBox"/>
```

Comment: Does that property has to be a DependencyProperty?

Comment: Depending on the declaration of your Text property (which should be a DependencyProperty), you may have to explicitly set a TwoWay binding: {Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: It can be a DependencyProperty (use the propdp code snippet in Visual Studio) or the object can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: I actually don't need it as a two way, i only want that when the Window.Text is changed the TextBox.Text should be updated.

Comment: @Mart, can you be more specific, I think I like what you say

Comment: If you define your Window.Text as a DependencyProperty, the TextBox.Text will be updated automatically. Example of a DP definition:

public string Text
{
 get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
 set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Window), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

Comment: Thanks for your effort and sorry for not telling you my exact question. I meant how could I do this using the INotifyPropertyChanged tha you said above.

Comment: The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used when you want to bind a whole object rather than a single dependency property. Basically each of your object's property raises a PropertyChanged event in its setter. This way WPF knows the value has changed and reflects it to the user interface.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, what message do I have to call at the property (a regular property, right?)?

Comment: Each time a (regular) property value is changed, a PropertyChanged event is raised. Example:
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
private string _text;
public string Text { get { return _text; } set { if (_text != value) { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); } } }

Comment: But I am using it in a window where the OnPropertyChanged method is already implemented asking me to pass DependencyPropertryChangedEventArgs as a param?

Comment: As I told you, if your property is attached to the window, you should have a DependencyProperty as described before. The INotifyPropertyChanged technique is used when you bind to a custom class.